# How can i use Transliteration in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have some requirement for my React-native project and i'm got stuck how to create a project like this - For example : If user typing in Text-field and suppose if he/she typed "Hello" then its automatically translated into selected language and set over there on Text-field,similarly like Facebook uses language transliteration when some wrote a post in selected language and gets translated into selected language.I'll gave you one more example of Google-Indic Keyboard.They will provide us regional input keyboard.How to accomplish this task in react-native for Ios/ANDROID ? Help!!! Note : i have google cloud translation API KEY

Comment: Please describe what steps you've taken to try and answer the problem, what issue you are running into, and how to reproduce the error. StackOverflow is not a place to as for suggestions or for tutorials. See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i 'm using power translator that will translated the input value which i 'm gonna typing in text input everything is working fine! But my problem is that i want to set my translated text again on textinput how can i do this here my code snippet :
<TextInput 
      style={{color:'black',width:width-60, borderColor: 'black'}}
      underlineColorAndroid='black'
      placeholderTextColor="black"
      onChangeText={ (textValue) => this.setState({input: textValue}) }
      value={this.props.input} 
      />

      <PowerTranslator
      text={this.state.input} />
      </View>

Comment: Again, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Edit what you wrote into your question with proper formatting and edit the question for better clarity.